# Small font all 'new' messages suddenly in Gmail on Ubuntu in Opera, why?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, gmail, opera, ubuntu-11.10

This seemed to happen out of the blue.
I have been using Opera for years.

I can't find anywhere in Gmail to change the default font that is used in Opera.

Ubuntu is Version 11
Opera is version 11.6

In Firefox the font is normal size.

I have tried playing around with both all the browser setting I can find plus Ubuntu system settings (I had seen some mentions of Opera using the system default font sometimes) but no success so far.

Really bumming as I have been using Opera for two years and if I can't resolve it I will not be able to use it.

I can switch to Firefox but I don't want to.

Comment: OK, I'm flagging again as off-topic. I understand that it is technically within SU's broad scope, but I think that it will get more attention from Ubuntu experts at askubuntu.com. And @studiohack, you can feel free to delete any of my comments on this thread, as it is too long and too meta.

Comment: @EricWilson this question is on-topic for SU, and we only migrate to SE sites with overlaping scope *if the OP specifically asks us to*.  Otherwise, the question stays, as the last time the OP indicated his preference, it was on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just showed up on my mac so not just Ubuntu !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in Opera 11.6+: http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1157352&t=1323469056&page=1#comment10836852

I'm zooming the web page when writing emails now (and zooming out when done). Works quite nice (and you get the editor ~fullscreen :)

**[Note from michael: Accepted this as it "answers" the question, but also see workaround below!]**

Answer (score 3):

[This comment](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1185972&t=1328736303&page=1#comment11054202) provides a style-sheet fix:

> 1. Create a file containing this: .LW-avf {font-size: small !important;}
> 2. Save this file as gmail.user.css into the Opera folder `/usr/share/opera/styles/`
> 3. Log in to your Gmail account. RIGHT click on any empty space and select "Edit Site Preferences".  Select the "Display" tab. Go to "My
>    style sheet" textbox and browse for the gmail.user.css file.

Then reload the page.

Comment: Yes this fixed it!  Hard to not to change my accept, so made my q about why but also gave this workaround fix an upcheck.

Comment: Unfortunately the same fix doesn't work for Windows :(

Comment: For a Mac I put the file in my home directory and then selected it via step 3.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Gmail support discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=3877ac0878e42773&hl=en) the cause of this problem is that Opera used to have the font too large in gmail, for which Google created an Opera-specific fix.

In 11.60, Opera fixed their bug, but Google has yet to remove their fix, so that the now too small text returns back to its normal size.