# How to fix Gmail font preferences In Opera

Tags: gmail, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small font when typing new for all messages suddenly in Gmail on Ubuntu in Opera, can't change it](https://superuser.com/questions/366044/small-font-when-typing-new-for-all-messages-suddenly-in-gmail-on-ubuntu-in-opera)

Recently whenever I use Opera to access Gmail, messages compose in the small font size instead of "normal".

Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Note that the other question has both the reason for the error and also a great little css file workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Through a [Gmail support page](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8260) I found a [lab](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=29418) that would let you set default font preferences.

I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but it will fix your problem.